Expected and Variance of the Squared Sample Correlation
I would like to obtain the expectation and variance of the squared sample correlation ($\operatorname{E}(R_{lk}^2)$ and $V(R_{lk}^2)$) between two random variables $l$ and $k$ following a bivariate normal distribution.
I have been trying to trace back the results of a paper, stating that:
\begin{align}\operatorname{E}(R_{lk}^2)\approx R_{lk}^2 + \frac{(1 - R_{lk}^2)}{N}&\end{align}
where $R_{lk}^2$ is the observed squared sample correlation. They claim that this result can be obtained with the $delta-method$.
My understanding of the $delta-method$ is that one can obtain an approximate expression for the Variance of a function of a random variable, such that:
\begin{align}Var(f(X))={({f'(X)})^2}Var(X)&\end{align}
Any idea how to get these results?

WLOG, assume $E(X) = E(Y) = 0$. Sample correlation is, omitting lower order terms,
$$\hat{\rho}_n = \frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}X_jY_j}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}X_j^2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n} Y_j^2}}.$$
Apply the central limit theorem to get
$$\sqrt{n}((\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}X_jY_j, \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}X_j^2,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}Y_j^2) - (Cov(X, Y), Var(X), Var(Y))) \to_d N(0, \Sigma),$$
where $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of $(XY, X^2, Y^2)$. Then let $f(c, v, w) = \frac{c}{\sqrt{v}\sqrt{w}}$. The delta-method yields
$$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\rho}_n - \rho) \to_d N(0, a^T\Sigma a),$$
where
$$a = \nabla f(Cov(X, Y), Var(X), Var(Y)).$$
We write this informally as $\hat{\rho}_n \approx N(\rho, \frac{1}{n}a^T \Sigma a)$. If you want the asymptotic distribution for $\hat{\rho}_n^2$, just apply delta method again.

ok, I will need to study your response carefully. But is there a closed expression for the variance?

@CafféSospeso For $Var(\hat{\rho}_n)$ there doesn't appear to be a closed form. I showed $Var(\hat{\rho}_n) \approx \frac{1}{n}a^T\Sigma a$. I haven't done this computation myself, but I believe $a^T \Sigma a = 1 - \rho^2$, as this is a frequently cited result.

Please have a look at this thread where I have formulated the question in a different way: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/647006/derive-the-expectation-and-variance-of-squared-sample-correlation-delta-method?noredirect=1#comment1211895_647006
